# jQuery: For events bound with .on(), which is better/faster: expressly removing events, or letting remove() handle it?

Tags: jquery, events

In  jQuery, for events bound with .on(), which is better/faster: expressly removing events, or letting remove() handle it?

Letting remove() handle it is easier, but is there a performance hit (and if so, how much of one?), or is it better to keep track of bound events and expressly unbind them prior to doing the remove()?

Comment: Events are not bound to elements, event handlers are. Events fire at elements.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the jQuery developers know best which events are bound and how to effectively remove them: Let jQuery handle it in `remove()`. I don't know any script that manually unbinds the events because of performance reasons (Which are probably marginal)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to remove them manually, you would have to remove the events, their data, and all data that jQuery uses on the element as well as any data that any plugins may be storing on the element. It would be much safer/easier and more than likely faster to simply use `.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

use .off();

You can use it as unbind/undelegate etc etc....

```
$("#item").off("click", "a");
```

Comment: That's the question - is it worth it to track the events, and call off() on each one before remove()ing, or just remove() and let jQuery handle it?

Comment: are you entirely getting rid of the element on the page? or just removing the event bind? If you're removing the element, and you don't do a whole lot of other work in the page, or continue adding and removing elements, I don't see why you'd have to unbind it. But if this is a large application, it's best to free up the memory locations.